# Filter output and push filtered data into array with bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I wasn't totally sure if I should have posted this here, serverfault or linux and unix but...

What I'm trying to do here is take the output from this command:

```
ps -eo pid -eo ecpu -eo command | sort -k 2 -r | grep -v PID | grep -i frmweb
```

[image: an example of it is here]

... and apply a filter to which it only looks at processes that are using cpu. ( > 0 )

... and then take what's left and push the PIDs (first column) into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put the process IDs in a bash array called `nonzero`:

```
nonzero=($(ps -eo pid -eo ecpu -eo command | sort -k 2 -r | awk '/frmweb/ && !/PID/ && $2+0>0{print $1}'))
```

`awk` commands have the form of `condition {commands}`.  Here, the condition consists of three conditions and-ed together (`&&` means logical-and):

```
/frmweb/ && !/PID/ && $2+0>0
```

- The first condition says that the line must contain `frmweb`.
- The second requires that it must not contain `PID`
- The third requires that the second column, denoted in `awk` by `$2`, be greater than zero.  `Awk` can do both string and numeric comparisons. Although likely not necessary here, the use of addition, as in `$2+0`, forces the use of numeric comparison.

If all three conditions are met, the first column (the process ID) is printed via:

```
print $1
```

Note that `awk` removes the need for the two `grep` commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_of_pids=( $(your-pipeline | awk '$2 > 0.0 {print $1}') )
```